# What is the available space on my disk, exactly

Tags: disk-usage

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and trying to find out how much space on my SSD I used. I'm getting different numbers from three tools I tried. Command line shows 73GB used:

```
paul@paul-desktop:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             8147768        0   8147768   0% /dev
tmpfs            1634036     3644   1630392   1% /run
/dev/sda1      114596460 73090608  35641592  68% /
tmpfs            8170168   707284   7462884   9% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            8170168        0   8170168   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
....
```

QDirStat shows 39.6GB used:

[image]

System Monitor shows 74.8GB used:

[image]

What is the actual space used?

Comment: Trust the `df -h` output and not these qdirstat reports

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read a complete root filesystem with QDirStat, you will not see the content of directories that you don't have permissions for; that is only normal. The latest stable QDirStat version 1.6.1 will show that more clearly; older versions will show a lock icon for those directories (and they are mentioned in the log).

To see everything, run it with root permissions:

```
xhost +          
sudo qdirstat /
```

Also, you appear to be using Btrfs on you root filesystem. Btrfs has inherent problems reporting disk usage; it needs disk space not only for files and directories, but also for the copy-on-write feature and for snapshots.

I just yesterday wrote this up for new QDirStat features that I am working on:

https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/doc/Btrfs-Free-Size.md

Also, please notice that QDirStat (like most disk related tools) uses 1024-based units: 1 kB = 1024 Bytes; 1 MB = 1024 kB; 1 GB = 1024 MB etc.; again, the latest QDirStat version can also show you the exact byte sizes if you are interested in byte-level precision.

--

Stefan Hundhammer (HuHa)

QDirStat author

Answer (score 2):

In addition to my answer above about missing permissions, I also wrote up some more differences: Byte size vs. used blocks of a file:

https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/issues/134

In short, the "du" and "df" commands take disk space into account that is wasted due to files not completely using all of their last disk block, so some of it remains unused (albeit allocated).

QDirStat on the other hand strictly uses the byte size reported by the stat() system call; it does not make any assumptions what happens to partly used disk blocks. That GitHub issue explains why.

**Edit 2020-06-11:**

I just added support for allocated sizes as well. Check out the link above for more details.

Answer (score 1):

QDirStat appears to be only showing the size of files you own. For example `/boot` shows as zero bytes but in reality it would have to have something in it:

For example:

```
$ du /boot -s -h

du: cannot read directory '/boot/efi': Permission denied
1.2G    /boot

$ sudo du /boot -s -h
1.3G    /boot
```

Another important consideration is some utilities list the size of the bytes in a file while others list the space a file occupies which is number of bytes rounded up to the block size which is generally 4,096 bytes or 4K.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the output of `df` is not in GBs. If you use `df -h` instead, the output should be similar to that of the system monitor - 74.8GB.

QDirStat report is strange, I don't know what to make of it.

Comment: `df -h` produces `/dev/sda1       110G   70G   34G  68%`, which is further away from 74.8GB shown by System Monitor than 73GB produced by `df`

Answer (score 0):

`df` and system monitor are correct. Many gnome apps assume `1 GB = 1000 MB` where as it is `1 GB = 1024 MB`.

If you do the math, the results are clear.